# Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.0

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Initially, I had it working (can compile), but after watching the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cNPCgJW8c-E) and adding Google Play services in the SDK Tools, things stopped working with:

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
>   Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.0.
>        Required by:
>            project :app
>   Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.0.
>        Required by:
>            project :app

I Googled, and everyone says update the SDK Tools, but I don't see any update options:

[image]

Are my SDK tools already the latest? What is causing the error message?

Comment: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/08/some-updates-to-apps-using-google-play.html

Comment: Thanks. Added that `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }` line and the error goes away.